# Filter search results web part by field on page with multiple values

Tags: search-results, managed-metadata

I have a Search Result web part set up straight in the page layout. The intention is that users cannot change the Search Results web part, but they can change a field on the page that then filters the Search Results webpart.

And everything is working great... until the user selects more than one value in the field (managed metadata field). Then it continues to show only results filtered by the first Word.

Here's my Query:

```
path:"http://cmsshp.ccta.dk/sites/meddelelser/" (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") (owstaxIdEmnebank:{Page.Emner til værktøjsside})
```

owstaxIdEmnebank = the managed metadatafield used elsewhere

Emner til værktøjsside = the managed metadatafield used here (on the page)

Any clues how I tell SharePoint to check all selected values in "Emner til værktøjsside"?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you can filter by a list of items (Maybe using WORDS() operator or ALL() operator) but in my experience it's difficult to make it work the way you want it to.  Check this post for a good reference on the operators:

http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/s15e01-kql-basics.html

An easier way might be to have two fields where they only enter one managed metadata value in each.

{? fieldname:{Page.param1}}
{? fieldname:{Page.param2}}

or something like that.

Also I don't know if you know, but you can use the ? operator to only include a section of the query (inside {}'s) when a value is present.  My syntax might be wrong, but google or fiddle with it.

Comment: I've now tried all possible combinations of WORDS(), ANY(), ALL(), ? and nothing seems to Work, sadly... I'd rather not use the solution, where the user has to select their Query Words in a series of boxes rather than in one box. Anyone has other ideas?